# Number of elements inside an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array and want to find the numbers of elements inside. 
What i want is this:

```
char array[100];

array[0] = 'a';
array[1] = 'b';
array[2] = 'c';
```

The number of elements in this case is 3.
That's what i want.

How can i find that value?

Comment: You are mistaken in concept. That array has 100 elements.`array[3]` (and later) _do_ have a value of some kind. I haven't used vanilla C in a long time, but IIRC the exact value will be implementation dependent, where some implementations may 0-initialize the array and others will just take whatever garbage might have been in that memory space already.

Comment: C is a low-level language. It doesn't track things like that for you--you have to do it yourself. `char array[100]` does nothing but allocate memory for 100 characters. They aren't initialized, so their values are random, and C has no concept of an "empty" or "filled" space.

Comment: How many "used" elements? You already know that, because you wrote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do

```
char array[100];
printf("%s", array);
```

you'd get `abc`. To find the elements of a char array you can use `strlen()` function.

```
printf("%zu", strlen(array)); //would give you 3
```

`strlen()` returns the number of elements which has a value inside and not a trash memory until it encounters a `\0` null element.

About `strlen()` function, since commentator asked me why

Taken by http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/

**Gets string length**

> The length of a C string is determined by the terminating
>   null-character: A C string is as long as the number of characters
>   between the beginning of the string and the terminating null character
>   (without including the terminating null character itself). This should
>   not be confused with the size of the array that holds the string. For
>   example:

```
char mystr[100]="test string";
```

> defines an array of characters with a size of 100 chars, but the C
>   string with which mystr has been initialized has a length of only 11
>   characters. Therefore, while sizeof(mystr) evaluates to 100,
>   strlen(mystr) returns 11.

**Since people have had concerns about the null terminator..**

You can use `memset()` function to set all the elements to null.

```
char array[100];
memset(&array, '\0', 100);
```

when you declaring elements you can set the last element to a null terminator.

```
char array[100];

int elemenNum = 0;

array[elemenNum] = 'a';
elemenNum++;
array[elemenNum] = 'b';
elemenNum++;
array[elemenNum] = 'c';
elemenNum++;
array[elemenNum] = '\0'; //Null terminator
elemenNum++;
```

or you can just set the numbers manually. however you like.

Lastly, as Lee mentioned in the comments,

> And of course all of this only works if you set values in order, 0, 1,
>   2, 3... If you set #1, then #2, then #5, then #9, `strlen()` will not
>   work.

Comment: I don't you can count on 0-initialization with vanilla C.

Comment: Why would `strlen` work? Given the code posted in the question.

Comment: what do you mean, just use `memset()`? @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: The OP's example would not be guaranteed to work with `strlen` as there is no guarantee of a null terminator.

Comment: why not just use `memset()` after the declaration of the array? @ChristianGibbons

Comment: And of course all of this only works if you set values in order, 0, 1, 2, 3... If you set #1, then #2, then #5, then #9, strlen() will still be 0.

Comment: It could be done, but you did not do so in your example.  Also, depending on how it was being used, it might be a waste of cpu cycles to clear out the entire array rather than just appending a null terminator after you are done adding characters.

Comment: Well I gave an example now @ChristianGibbons

Comment: yes that's the only way since that's a rule for string arrays, also why would you not set them in an order anyways? @LeeDanielCrocker

Comment: The op said nothing about "strings", whatever they are.

Comment: I find it a little funny that you used an integer in your example to manually keep track of the number of elements in the array so that you could use strlen to keep track of the elements of the array.

Comment: I know just to make it more clear, i also mentioned it could be done manually @ChristianGibbons

Comment: `printf("%d", strlen(array)); //would give you 3` is wrong. It might give the right answer on a littleendian system, not a bigendian one. Please use `printf("%zu", strlen(array));`

Comment: why did it get downvoted? please specify a reason for better answers.

Comment: @turmuka Welcome to "spite votes" on Stack Overflow! Some people aren't downvoting to improve your answer, but to show that they are mad at you for answering the question at all, because in their opinion it's a bad question. I think that the best approach is to ignore these votes.

Answer (score 2):

> The number of elements in this case is 3.

The number of elements in this case is still 100. The first three are initialized, while the remaining values are not set.

If you do not plan to treat null characters as valid in your code, pre-initialize the array with zeros, like this:

```
char array[100] = { 0 };
```

Now you can iterate `array` from index zero, and stop upon reaching the first `'\0'` character, or reaching the end of `array`, whichever comes first.

Comment: Or just keep track of how many elements you set, like a high-level language would do for you.